# Desktop wallpaper changes only apparently

Tags: desktop

I've followed all the solutions proposed to make the desktop wallpaper change, as it apparently it doesn't, but the only solution I can achieve is getting the default wallpaper after rebooting.

However my issue is slightly different than the one other users have reported.

When I change the desktop, I can see in the system preferences that it has changed, and even when using mission control, or switching from a space to another, I see the new wallpaper, until I go back to the desktop (either the current one or the new one).

So it seem that the wallpaper actually changed, but is "overlapped" by the default one, as it's using multiple layers.

I'm not sure if I've made the issue clear.

I don't have any application playing with the wallpaper (I use to have Kuvva (www.kuvva.com) installed, but then I've removed using a specific uninstaller).

Oh, and my system is a Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Anyone has a possible solution?

**UPDATE**
When changing the wallpaper, the system log doesn't show anything in particular, except, sometime these two lines (but this is not a constant):

```
Sep  6 13:05:36 new-host.station System Preferences[23804]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Sep  6 13:05:36 new-host.station System Preferences[23804]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
S
```

The uninstaller I've used has been provided by the Kuvva support team: this is the only feedback I got from them. Further question never got answered.
And no, I didn't install it from the App Store.

Comment: Did you by kuvva on the Mac App Store? What specific uninstaller did you use? My guess is that kuvva (or better said, the remains of it) are causing this behavior. What gets logged in `/var/log/system.log` when you change wallpapers (use Utilities/Console.app)?

Comment: @jaume I've answered updating my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with my desktop wallpaper after uninstalling Kuvva as well. In my case, removing the desktop plist file solved the problem.

To do this, run the following command from the terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Desktop.plist
```

Then log out and log back in. Be aware that this will also return any other desktop settings to their defaults. If you're uneasy about just outright deleting this plist, you can always make a backup copy first.

Comment: I did try this already and the only thing I've got is resetting the desktop, but I'm still unable to change it. Or, as I said in my question, it does change, but in what it seem a sort of "layer" behind the stuck desktop.